# React native state map. how to get only 1 value rendered?

Tags: arrays, react-native, modal-dialog, maps

I have this screen witch shows all uploaded adverts:

.
[image]

When I select one of the adverts, it should show me new screens with all pictures and details from that specific ad.

But instead it shows me detailed adverts but for all adverts, not for one...

[image]

Here is the code how I display my values from array:

```
{

                    this.state.ads && 
                    this.state.ads.map((ads) => {
                        var s = require('../styles')
                        var id = this.state.indexas
                        return(
                            <View key={id} style={s.adContainer}>
                                <TouchableHighlight>
                                    <View style={{justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center"}}>

                                   <SafeAreaView>
                                        <Carousel
                                            sliderWidth={screenWidth}
                                            sliderHeight={screenWidth}
                                            itemWidth={screenWidth - 60}
                                            data={ads.images}
                                            renderItem={this._renderItem}
                                            hasParallaxImages={true}
                                        />
                                    </SafeAreaView> 
                                 </View>
                                 </TouchableHighlight>
                                 <TouchableHighlight>
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                        <View style={s.listedItemCell}>
                                    <Text>Textas:</Text> 
                                    <Text>{ads.text}</Text>
                                 </View>

                                 <View style={s.listedItemCell}>
                                    <Text>Paskelbta:</Text> 
                                    <Text>{ads.timestamp}</Text>
                                 </View>

                                 <View style={s.listedItemCell}>
                                    <Text>Kaina:</Text> 
                                    <Text>{ads.kaina}</Text>
                                 </View>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })
                }
```

I can access everything with this code. But I need only 1 value with specific index (this.state.indexas)

I am receiving error it says that all ids are same ( thats what i want, specific ID ) but still shows me all data from the array...

Comment: could you explain your problem a bit more

Comment: @SDushan I have updated my question a bit... it is very simple question, it might be just too hard to explain :(

Comment: what is the value of ```this.state.indexas```?

Comment: @SDushan the value is INT NUMBER, it is exactly id of the ad which i want to show, cuz I pass it on advert click function 

`showPost = (index) => {
        this.setState({ indexas: index })
        this.setState({
            modalVisibility: !this.state.modalVisibility
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` prop to the `View` component should be unique. But in your case, you are assigning `this.state.indexas` as `key` which contain only the select index.

Since you are using `map` in JS, the second parameter of the `map` contains the current index of the particular element in that array.

So change your code as below,

```
{
  this.state.ads &&
    this.state.ads.map((ads, index) => {
      var s = require("../styles");
      return (
        <View key={index} style={s.adContainer}>
          ...
        </View>
      )
    })
}
```

This way, you'll be sure that your key is not duplicated.

**Edit**

Since you want to display a specific item according to your selected value. You can use `filter` or `find` in JS.

```
{
  this.state.ads &&
    this.state.ads
      .filter(item => item.id == this.state.indexas)
      .map(ads => {
        var s = require("../styles");
        return (
          <View key={this.state.indexas} style={s.adContainer}>
            ...
          </View>
        );
      });
}
```

Hope this will helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: you didint got what i want to say... I had code like this before, but it shows me all items from map... i want only 1

Comment: @RokasDevolskis do you want to display only one item that matches ```this.state.indexas``` value?

Comment: yes. I have already figured it out. I have send ads value insted of index and assigned to new state, then I got rid of map and displayed only new state. thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: @RokasDevolskis Awesome! I am glad you figured it out!. but anyway I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. I think your way is a bit more efficiant yes? I will mark it as answer cuz that would do the job as well. I never knew about filter function ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out. I have send ads value instead of index and assigned array value to new state, then I got rid of map and displayed only new state.